# Why do elements jump between ignoring and acknowledging margins based on parents' padding?

Tags: html, css

In my experience, to get many of my elements' items to properly acknowledge their children's margins, I've had to apply an imperceptibly small amount of padding to it. For instance:

```
<style type="text/css">
    :root {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    body>div {
        outline: 1px solid #00F;
    }
    div>div {
        margin: 1em;
        outline: 1px solid #0F0;
    }

    #div1 {
        padding: 0;
    }
    #div2 {
        padding: 0.05px;
    }
    #div3 {
        padding: 10px;
    }
</style>

<div id="div1"><div>Div 1 (parent without padding)</div></div>
<div id="div2"><div>Div 2 (parent with imperceptible padding)</div></div>
<div id="div3"><div>Div 3 (parent with visible padding)</div></div>
```

renders basically as

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                               │
│┌─┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬─┐│
││ │Div 1 (parent without padding)                                           │ ││
│└─┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴─┘│
│                                                                               │
│┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐│
││ ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ ││
││ │Div 2 (parent with imperceptible padding)                                │ ││
││ └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘ ││
│└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘│
│┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐│
││                                                                             ││
││  ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐  ││
││  │Div 3 (parent with visible padding)                                    │  ││
││  └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘  ││
││                                                                             ││
│└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘│
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q4WqJ/

In this example, Div 2 is the one with the intended effect, but the means to attain it are... silly. **Why does this happen, and is there any way I can accomplish the effect I'm going for more semantically?**

Comment: The basic rules for [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is always a culprit when using floats. Typically, I do not add any "imperceptible" padding because I would expect the browser to round up and add 1px when you may not intend that to be the case. Instead, I avoid `margin-bottom` at all costs. Margin-left and margin-right do not cause issues. And if margin-top doesn't work, I add padding to the parent div or use some other sort of work around.

I know this doesn't give much insight to the inner workings but the strategy described above works like a charm has not yet failed me.

## Update

This behavior is called **margin-collapsing** and occurs only to top and bottom margins in certain specific cases; it does not affect inline elements.

this effect originates from Netscape 3 that used collapsing margins. While counterintutive the specs were changed to follow the (poor) standard set forth by netscape in those "dark ages." Do note that this is quirks mode or some voodoo magic happening. This is actually defined partly by the specs.

margin-collapse will take the max of all the possible margins. So in your case, the parent div has no top-margin and thus the inner div (which has a larger top margin) is taken into effect. Add padding changes this behavior because padding cancels out the continuity in the max calcualtion of which margin to use.

Changing the display type is another method to do this. Such as `display: table` because unlike 15 years ago, CSS was able to define the spec instead of adopting a preexisting one.

Hope this give syou more insight. Search google for more.

Comment: I avoid `float` at all costs. `margin-right` and `-left` introduce problems when dealing with `inline-block`s. Also, this is pretty chatty, and has no real answer...

Comment: Adding `display: table` is an alternative to adding padding. FYI

Comment: Though that also removes the ability for it to be full-width @ProfileTwist

Comment: Here I updated my answer. That should give you a lot more info.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving `overflow: auto;` to it. Also, this link might explain the reason. http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins

Comment: That fixes it, but I'm worried about scrollbars appearing when I don't expect them.